# Why does my CSS seem to change after deployment?

Tags: css, reactjs, deployment

Hey guys I'm a fairly noob developer im attempting to make a website for a local business and for some reason when I go to deploy my site it changes the font size and makes it smaller and some of my styling in general is different. Any ideas why it does this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What code have you written? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Many DOM elements have flexible size, so their final styles depend on the content size. For example, if you decreases the font size, there is more space to show more elements, then the browser would lay out differently to use the new space. Also, unit `em` directly depends on the current font size (see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139455/what-does-the-unit-em-depend-upon-in-style-sheets-css)).

To have a better control of the final output, you can use `min-width`, `max-width`, etc.